# How to add additional Tag for tiff file

Tags: python, tiff, python-imaging-library

I am trying to read and save a tiff file with some additional Tags, when I make a new image that works well but when I open an image then trying to write some meta tags back it is not working (The image can be written but it will keep the original tag without any change).

I attached my testing code, I am appreciated for any help!

```
from PIL import Image, TiffImagePlugin
def test_custom_metadata():

    img = Image.open('myimage.tif')

    info = TiffImagePlugin.ImageFileDirectory()
    CustomTagId = 37000

    info[CustomTagId] = 6
    info.tagtype[CustomTagId] = 3 # 'short' TYPE

    Image.DEBUG=True
    TiffImagePlugin.WRITE_LIBTIFF = False # Set to True to see it break.
    img.save('./temp2.tiff', tiffinfo = info)

test_custom_metadata()
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Is there an error, if so, add the stacktrace to the post. Or is the image written but you can't see your custom tiff tag?

Comment: @Bernhard I make that clear, thanks!

Comment: Your code ran without error on my machine.

Comment: @BillBell the tag(37000) will not be added as expect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me with Pillow version 2.3:

```
from PIL import Image

image_1 = Image.open('input.tiff')
image_1.tag[37000] = 'my special tiff tag'
image_1.save('output.tiff', tiffinfo=image_1.tag)

image_2 = Image.open('output.tiff')
print image_2.tag[37000]
```

This prints `my special tiff tag` when running with an `input.tiff` in the current folder.

My understanding is that this only works when you don't use libtiff for writing the file. When using libtiff custom tags are ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your response! After I change my pillow from 4.1 to 2.3 it works, it might because of the version issue.

Comment: One more thing, is your pillow 2.3 img.save() works properly? When I save the image, it does not display correctly. img.show() is correct, but after saving it, some of them becomes blank. Thanks for your patience! Save as '.png' works. Does 2.3 support '.tiff'...

Comment: I think the differnce is that 2.3 uses per default its own TIFF writer and with a newer version the default is to use libtiff behind the scenes. In a newer version you should be able to turn of writing with libtiff, like you do in your example with `TiffImagePlugin.WRITE_LIBTIFF = False`. The issue with the saved TIFF file is likely due to some unsupported functionality in the PIL TIFF writer implementation at least in the old version.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! So if I could not use either new version to add tag or old version to write correct image, is there any other way or library to do so, so appreciated that!

Answer (score -2):

For someone interested that topic:

[C/C++ method to add custom tag for tiff file](http://www.asmail.be/msg0054585832.html)

That will perfectly solve the problem

Comment: This question is tagged as 'python', so this is not relevant.