# Adding a WANG Annotation to an existing TIFF image w/Python & PILLOW

Tags: annotations, python-imaging-library, tiff

Part of the issue is that Pillow's ReadtheDocs is down, and GoogleFu is getting me nowhere...

The annotation is a "big black" box (stamp) style.

So we have an TIFF file, and an ANN file.  I believe the annotation (ANN) file is the extracted TAG information for the TIFF annotation that I am trying to re-add to the original tiff file.

```
>>> im = Image.open(test)
>>> im2 = Image.open(test2)
>>> meta_dict = {TAGS[key] : im2.tag[key] for key in im2.tag.keys()}
>>> meta_dict
{'ImageWidth': (2544,), 'ImageLength': (0,), 'BitsPerSample': (1,), 'Compression': (1,), 'PhotometricInterpretation': (0,), 'StripOffsets': (0,), 'Orientation': (1,), 'SamplesPerPixel': (1,), 'RowsPerStrip': (0,), 'StripByteCounts': (0,), 'XResolution': ((300, 1),), 'YResolution': ((300, 1),), 'Wang Annotation': b'\x04\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00OiGroup\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00[Untitled]\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00OiIndex\x00\n\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00PxVerStr\r\x00\x00\x0056.1.11.1571\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00PxDPI\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00PxStorag\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'ResolutionUnit': (2,), 'Software': ('Pixel Translations Inc., PIXTIFF Version 56.1.218.1571',), 'NewSubfileType': (0,)}
>>> im.tag[32932] = meta_dict["Wang Annotation"]
>>> im.save("test.tif")
>>> im.show()
```

From reading StackOverflow, etc, I thought the code above would be enough to "merge" the annotation from im2 to im1?  But I'm not seeing it....

[How to add additional Tag for tiff file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283224/how-to-add-additional-tag-for-tiff-file)

Could you give me any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: You can rewrite third line as `meta_dict = {TAGS[key] : value for key, value in im2.tag.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed `tiffinfo` parameter. Try to save the file like this:

```
im.save("test.tif", tiffinfo=im.tag)
```